# Git pre-commit isn't commiting

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have written a `pre-commit` hook to run `golinter` before the commit

```
#!/bin/bash

REV_NUMBER=$(git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD)

if [[ "$REV_NUMBER" = "" ]]; then
  exit 0
fi

echo "golangci-lint run --new-from-rev $REV_NUMBER"
golangci-lint run --new-from-rev $REV_NUMBER

exit 1
```

The pre-commit files lies in my `<project>\.git\hooks\pre-commit`.

When i do `git commit -m "Message"`, The pre-commit hook runs and does the linting part. But even after successful completion, the `git commit` never happens. I mean the files still remain in staging area.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the exit 1 at the end or replace with exit 0. With exit 1 you are signaling to the invoking process (commit) that something went wrong.

Comment: thanks. One more quick question. given that my hook resides at project leve. does it mean that anyone who pulls the project will have these hooks configured? or does everyone has to configure them manually?

Comment: No, each person that clones the project will have to configure the hooks for their local clone. One suggestion would be to version the in a separate folder with your project and create a script to move them under .git/hooks when they setup the project. If you are using a package manager to setup dependencies, you may be able to find a plugin or after install script that does this automatically.